# How create a grafana plugin to previous version

Tags: plugins, grafana

I am following [this tutorial](https://grafana.com/tutorials/build-a-panel-plugin/#3) to create my own plugin to grafana 6.7.3.
However, at the beginning I can see:

> **IMPORTANT**: This tutorial is currently in **beta** and requires Grafana
>   7.0, which is scheduled for release in May. Some of the features mentioned may not work for earlier versions.

So, when I go to Configuration -> Plugins -> my-plugin, I get the following errors:

> Error Loading Plugin

And:

> This template is a starting point for building Grafana Panel Plugins
>   in Grafana 7.0+

I think it is because `@next` param to create the plugin:

```
npx "@grafana/toolkit"@next plugin:create my-plugin
```

But, I have tried to use with no `@next` param and with `@6.7.3` and nothing did work.

```
npx "@grafana/toolkit" plugin:create my-plugin
npx "@grafana/toolkit"@6.7.3 plugin:create my-plugin
```

Is there any way to create plugin to 6.7.3 version?